# Show that $\mathbb{E}(\log f_{X}(X))\geq\mathbb{E}(\log f_{Y}(X))$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the discrete random variables with joint mass function $f$.

$f_X$ denotes the marginal mass function for $X$, which means $f_{X}(x)=\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\sum_{y}f(x,y)$.

$f_{Y}$ is defined similarly.

I got a trouble in proving that $\mathbb{E}(\frac{f_{Y}(X)}{f_X(X)}-1)=0$, which is derived from $\log x\leq x-1$.

I have tried to write $\mathbb{E}(f_{X}(X))$ and $\mathbb{E}(f_{Y}(Y))$ clearly, namely $\mathbb{E}(f_{X}(X))=\mathbb{E}(f_X\circ X)=\sum_{x_i}f_X(x_i)\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)=\sum_{x_i}\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)^2$,

and $\mathbb{E}(f_Y(X))=\sum_{x_i}f_Y(x_i)\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)=\sum_{x_i}\mathbb{P}(Y=x_i)\mathbb{P}(X=x_i)$

However it doesn't seem to any help, I don't know how to do after that.

Any help is welcomed, I will appreciate it.

---

Thanks for the correct from geetha290krm.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(\frac{f_{X}(X)}{f_Y(X)}-1)=0$ is false. $\mathbb{E}(\frac{f_{Y}(X)}{f_X(X)}-1)=0$ is true.

Comment: yes, you're right. It's my typo. Could you tell me why it is ture? Thank you.

Comment: You also need $X$ and $Y$ to  take the same values.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thanks for your help : )